# How to pass a variable to WinExist?

Tags: autohotkey

I need to do

```
if WinExist(%window%) {...}
```

however this doesnt work

`%window%` is set earlier to be equal to `%3%` which is a command line argument that should be only of type string pointing the AHK script to the window of intrest.

I tried replacing `%window%` with `%3%` however the code inside never gets run. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since WinExist() accepts a string parameter for the window title, you don't need to enclose the variable in `%`.

If you set `window` to the value of the 3rd command parameter then the following code should work.

```
window = %3%

if WinExist(window)
{
    Msgbox, Exists.
}
else
{
    Msgbox, Does not exist.
}
```

Note: `window`or `%3%` must exactly match the window title, or you must use `SetTitleMatchMode, 2`
 (see [SetTitleMatchMode](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTitleMatchMode.htm)).

Answer (score 2):

```
If WinExist(window)
```

is an [expression](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#Expressions), any variable names in its parameter should not be enclosed in percent signs.

By contrast, literal strings should be enclosed in double quotes:

```
If WinExist("Untitled - Notepad")
```